# Change external sharing options with PowerShell on tenant level

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, external-users

Is it possible to view and change the external sharing options on tenant level with PowerShell?

I mean these: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off

I looked at the `Get-SPOTenant` command, as this contains other sharing options, changed this setting, tried to find anything that changes but didn't see anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can change the external sharing in the tenant by the PowerShell command Set-SPOTenant.

You can use the Parameter “SharingCapability” in the PowerShell command Set-SPOTenant.

The valid values are:

ExternalUserAndGuestSharing (default) - External user sharing (share by email) and guest link sharing are both enabled.

Disabled - External user sharing (share by email) and guest link sharing are both disabled.

ExternalUserSharingOnly - External user sharing (share by email) is enabled, but guest link sharing is disabled.

For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

[Set-SPOTenant](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/set-spotenant?view=sharepoint-ps)

[Manage your SharePoint Online tenant with PowerShell.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2016/07/27/manage-your-sharepoint-online-tenant-with-powershell/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with following option:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential admin@domain.com
```

after connection, you can pick one the below option:

```
Set-SPOTenant -SharingCapability ExternalUserAndGuestSharing
Set-SPOTenant -SharingCapability ExternalUserSharingOnly
Set-SPOTenant -SharingCapability Disabled
```

[Managing Sharing and Access in SharePoint Online](https://richardjgreen.net/managing-sharing-access-sharepoint-online/)
But now there is catch, if external sharing is enabled and being used on many site collection:

> If you turn off external sharing for your entire environment and later
>   turn it back on, external users who previously had access to content
>   or documents on sites will regain access to them. If you know that
>   external sharing was previously turned on and in use for specific site
>   collections and you do not want external users to be able to regain
>   access if external sharing is ever turned on again globally, we
>   recommend that you first turn off external sharing for those specific
>   site collections.
>   [Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off)

Now you have to turn off the external sharing on the site collection where it was enabled, run below powershell to get that list:

```
Get-SPOSite | Select Url, SharingCapability
```

Now use the Set-SPoSite command to disable it.

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity ""Sitecolelction url" -SharingCapability Disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

To view existing external sharing configuration,

```
Get-SPOSite | select SharingCapability
```

To change or set sharing capability,

```
Set-SPoSite -SharingCapability <PermissionLevel>
```

Allowable permission levels are,

- ExternalUserAndGuestSharing – sets the permission level to Anyone
- ExternalUserSharingOnly – sets the permission level to New and
- Existing guests ExistingExternalUserSharingOnly – sets the permission
- level to Existing guests Disabled – sets the permission level to Only
  people in your organization

Source: [Enable external sharing in SharePoint Online](https://o365reports.com/2021/06/17/configure-external-sharing-in-sharepoint-online)